# SQL BCP within Powershell hangs

Tags: sql, powershell, bcp

I am new to BCP. I am tying to launch bcp.exe utility from Powershell but it hangs. Same command works fine command prompt. I am using `Invoke-Expression` to launch bcp.exe.

I am able to launch SQLCMD.exe without any problems.

This is my powershell.

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"

SQLCMD.EXE -b -E -S CORPSYSSQLDEV -d CORPSYSDM -Q "select top 10 * from t_test"

$psCommand = "bcp.exe ""testDB.dbo.t_test"" in  ""C:\temp\test\testFile20180919.txt"" -c -t""\t"" -T -S ""TESTSQLDEV"" -e c:\temp\NoahFolder\error.csv"

Write-Host $psCommand

Invoke-Expression $psCommand
```

This is the result of $psCommand.

```
bcp.exe "testDB.dbo.t_test" in  "C:\temp\test\testFile20180919.txt" -c -t"\t" -T -S "TESTSQLDEV" -e c:\temp\test\error.csv
```

Which works fine from command prompt but when I run the powershell script its stuck.

[image]

I am able to launch SQLCMD.exe from powershell fine.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas or pointers.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using Start-Process -FilePath $bcp -ArgumentList $arglist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have searched more before asking here. [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/67eeaa3f-8aeb-40ee-90f1-b02ef7fe0cb1/powershell-invokeexpression-bcp?forum=winserverpowershell) post helped me. I was able to run BCP from powershell using Start-Process command.

```
$bcp = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
$arglist = @(
   #add all arguments.
)
Start-Process -FilePath $bcp -ArgumentList $arglist
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code what exactly is nodeobj? $bcp = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
$arglist = @(
$tableName,
"out $outputFile",
"-c -U $dbUserName",
"-P $dbPassword",
"-S $($nodeObj.DB_SERVER_NAME)",
"-d $($nodeObj.DB_NAME)",
"-e $bcpErrorPath"
)
Start-Process -FilePath $bcp -ArgumentList $arglist

Comment: Hi, answer should strictly be answers and replies like yours should be comments.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34586244)